# Can I restrict the installation of an enterprise app on an iOS device?

Tags: ios, mdm, airwatch

Supposedly AirWatch does allow this but I'm trying to find a solution using profiles and/or Apple Configurator.

Can I restrict an iOS device from installing an enterprise app (the device needs Safari access so in theory can download it from a web link). I was thinking this would be possible by not allowing the device to install any Profiles but I can't find a way to restrict this either.

Also, the "Allow installing apps" doesn't do the trick ... still allows you to install enterprise apps.

Comment: What's the gain from restricting the _installation_ of the application? Why not simply require privileges to _do_ anything with the application?

Comment: Good question. I'm trying to restrict everything except my enterprise application. I need to make 100% sure that the user isn't installing another enterprise or store application.

Comment: Ah, then I had even misunderstood the intent -- it isn't about forbidding _your_ application so much as _other_ applications. Gotit. :)

Comment: If, IF, you could jailbreak them you could just place the .app file in /Applications folder in restrict Safari and the App Store... Just a though

Comment: @TheDeveloper, very clever! I may need the ability for users to update them in the field so I'm going to have to give them access to Safari.

Comment: Or you could make a restricted browsing app that only goes to your site...

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't give the right to forbid an application. You CAN'T prevent users to install an application. But, you CAN prevent access to the AppStore. That way, users can't install any application, even if they get the link in the browser or somewhere else.

If you want your enterprise app installed on the device anyway, you can add it when you prepare your devices through AppleConfigurator. In the section "Prepare" you have a list of apps which will be installed on the device by default. Using AirWatch, I just put "AirWatch MDM Agent" in this list but you can add any application you want.

Another though is you can configur your devices as "Single-App". That means the devices will start with that application and only that application. No way to quit or return home, you just can use that application. It can be configured through the AppleConfigurator or an AirWatch profile (more flexible). Be careful if you do that through the AppleConfigurator, your app cannot access other apps and your only option to use the device normally after is to wipe it.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can restrict the installation of specific apps on an iOS Device. You need to use a Mac app called Apple Configurator. You can create a new Profile an then configure the 'Restrictions' to not allow a specific list of apps.

It's very handy to also setup the profile so it cannot be removed from the device without authorization.

In order to support this functionality the device you install the profile on has to be put into Supervised mode. You can do this with Apple Configurator. It requires wiping the device and setting it up as a 'New Phone". You cannot restore from a backup, slight downside, but worth it if you need to block specific apps.